Stimulsoft Data Table shows Extra lines
I have designed a report file and when I run my application (ASP MVC) to see the result, there are two extra lines in the right and left of my table. There should be a problem with the Table properties. How to solve this?
report file image
output image
I tried to have a table and change its column's width a little bit
but in the output, there are two extra lines.
when I set the width of its container which is a panel in this case, as much as the page it will be okay but I do not want to have a big table I want a small table in the center of my page.

Please, specify the version of Stimulsot Reports you use.
